# React native network error on android emulator

Tags: android, networking, react-native, offline

I am trying to handle the app offline situation in my app with react native. I have handled if the network is offline then don`t call the api and throw an exception and I am catching this exception in my code. bt my app still got crashed. I have attached the screen of the same.

[image]

```
componentWillMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', 
    this._handleConnectionChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', 
  this._handleConnectionChange);
}

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
   this.appState.isNetworkConnected = isConnected;
};

fetchDate() {
    if(this.appState.isNetworkConnected) {
        return axios.get('http://xx.xx.xx.xx/getdata');
    } else {
        throw 'network connection failed';
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code, please?

Comment: HI @SuhaylSH, I have updated question with code. let me know if it helps. or you need to any extra information on this. Thanks.